# Perform multiple rolling regression with different columns (independent variables)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-columns, xts, rolling-computation

How can I make multiple rolling regression whith y1 as dependent and y2, y3, etc as independent variables in separate regressions:

See example below:

```
library(xts)

df=data.frame(y1=rnorm(300),y2=rnorm(300),y3=rnorm(300),y4=rnorm(300),y5=rnorm(300),y6=rnorm(300))
data <- xts(df, Sys.Date()-300:1)
```

Below I make the rolling correlation of y1 over y2

```
rollingb <- rollapply(zoo(data),
                          width=20,
                          FUN = function(Z)
                          {
                            t = lm(formula=y1~ y2, data = as.data.frame(Z), na.rm=T);
                            return(t$coef)
                          },
                          by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

the result looks nice

```
plot(rollingb)
```

However now i want to test y1 ~ y3, y1 ~ y4, etc. (I have a dataset of in total 120 columns)

the following post got close, but I couldn't reproduce the coding:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438484/r-how-to-do-rolling-regressions-for-multiple-return-data-at-once-with-the-depe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438484/r-how-to-do-rolling-regressions-for-multiple-return-data-at-once-with-the-dep)

How can I adjust *rollingb* to get the job done?

The provided solution by @Yannis Vassiliadis works, however the follow up question rises how to unlist all the coefficients (betas) nicely into a matrix 
/ data.frame with the corresponding dates (as in the xts)?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
roll_lm <- lapply(2:ncol(data), function(x) rollapply(zoo(data[, c(1, x)]),
                          width=20,
                          FUN = function(Z)
                          { Z = as.data.frame(Z);
                            t = lm(formula=Z[, 1]~Z[, 2]);
                            return(t$coef)
                          },
                          by.column=FALSE, align="right"))
```

The output is a list with `ncol(data) - 1` elements, where the `ith` element is the outcome from a rolling regression of `y1` on `yi`.

Also, you can add:

```
names(roll_lm) <- paste0("y1~y",2:6) 
roll_lm2 <- plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(roll_lm) 
roll_lm3 <- cbind(roll_lm2, rep(names(roll_lm), each = 281)) # just to keep track of the names
```

Comment: what is the best way to unlist?  I use output <- matrix(unlist(roll_lm), ncol = ncol(data)-1, byrow = TRUE)b
names(output) <- names(data[,-1])  ,but then I lose the dates (from xts)

Comment: You can use something like `roll_lm<- plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(rollingb)`, which `rbind`s all the matrices together. You need to be careful and keep track of the dimensions though

Comment: i assume you mean `names(roll_lm) <- paste0("y1~y",2:6)
roll_lm2 <- plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(roll_lm) 
roll_lm3 <- cbind(roll_lm2, rep(names(roll_lm), each = 281)) # just to keep track of the names` to get it work?

Comment: @M_Sunny, yes! You're right, I forgot to update the names when transferring the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` from `purrr` to build a list of formulas along the lines of `y1 ~ y2` and `y1 ~ y3`. Then use each of these formulas in `lm`.

```
# these are the packages we are using
library(purrr)
library(useful)
library(coefplot)

# here's your data
df=data.frame(y1=rnorm(300),y2=rnorm(300),y3=rnorm(300),y4=rnorm(300),y5=rnorm(300),y6=rnorm(300))

# keep track of the response variable
response <- 'y1'
# we'll assume all the other variables are predictors
predictors <- setdiff(names(df), response)

# fit a bunch of models
models <- predictors %>% 
    # for each predictor build a formula like y1 ~ y2
    map(~build.formula(response, .x)) %>% 
    # for each of those fit a model
    map(lm, data=df)

# plot them for good measure
multiplot(models)
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract only the coefficients in a data.frame (dated with xts) ?

Comment: `coefplot::multiplot(models, plot=FALSE)`